# Изучение css

Tags: css

Я учусь верстать сайты. Занимаюсь по данным видео урокам - [курс верстки сайта](http://denweb.ru/put-veb-mastera_sod). Дошел до данного урока "[приступаем к CSS](http://denweb.ru/put-veb-mastera/uroki-verstki-sajtov-pristupaem-k-css.html)". Я знаком с css. Но мне часто не ясно почему автор применяет тот или иной прием. Это именно связанно с написанием css стилей. Что вы мне посоветуете делать?

Comment: Попробуйте обратиться к другому источнику.

Comment: А что вас именно смущает? То, что "приём", который использует автор этих курсов, отличается от ваших? Это вполне нормально. Зачастую, в решении определенной задачи, можно найти несколько способов.

Comment: не понимаю зачем и почему. А верстать я еще не умею.

Answer (score 3):

Идти от обратного. Ставить себе задачу и искать пути решения, таким образом, вы сами для себя будете решать какой именно прияем подходит именно вам, а так по мере проб и ошибок поймете какой прием или способ лучше использовать в данной конкретной ситуации, а какой нет.

Comment: пробовал сверстать простой шаблон, но без нужных знаний не смог его сверстать. В итоге перешел к изучению верстки по видео урокам.

Comment: Есть серии книг  "CSS сборник  рецептов"  это будет полезнее чем видео. Это лично мое мнение, книгиа она всегда ценнее. Только практика откроет тебе светлую сторону силы)

Answer (score 1):

**Видео уроки - просто ужас!** Лучший способ изучить (сам так учил) - это **[htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru)** . Потом поставить себе конкретную задачу (*я поставил себе задачу свёрстать и сразу натянуть шаблон на WordPress и я был в шоке, когда через 3-4 дня получил готовый шаблон*) и **добиваться своей цели**!

Answer (score 0):

Изучите базовые вещи, и все сразу поймется и не надо видео смотреть.

Возьмите div, начните менять у него свойства и смотрите на реакцию.

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам [cправочник](http://htmlbook.ru/css).

Почитай книги, где описаны приемы верстки. Видео в этом плане мало чем поможет. Как начинающий вариант.

Затем верстка макетов. [Основные типы макетов](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety).
Главный совет - пропускай мимо все, что говорится про баги в ие6,ие7 (они тебе не помогут, но это ускорит твое изучение) .
Загляни [сюда](http://forum.htmlbook.ru/index.php?showtopic=6481) и посмотри что говорят про ресурсы и сайты.